# ajuda com o split

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde, estou tentando modificar um script que estou criando para criar uma pagina simples na web, o inicio do codigo ate consegui criar, porem estou com dificuldades em separar o resultado, tipo: no codigo que criei voce inseri um valor e nele retorna 52 resultados diferentes, e com isso quero separar de em blocos, seria um total de 13 blocos, o primeiro contem o resultado de 1 a 4, o segundo de 5 a 8 e assim por diante, porem alem disso quero somar o resultado, e nao estou conseguindo, busquei na internet opçoes e cheguei ao split, porem nao consigo encaixar no script que estou criando, segue abaixo o codigo.

```
var plan = prompt("Valor depositado.");
for (var i =1; i<=52; i++){
    console.log(`${i} = ${i*plan}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendi o sentido disso. Talvez você esteja tentando resolver um problema mais simples mas resolveu perguntar como fazer da forma que imaginou, a qual não seria a ideal.

Para armazenar os resultados de 4 em quatro, você pode usar o operador `%`, o módulo, que te dá o resultado da divisão. Se o resultado for 0, o número é divisível por 4, e você começa a preencher outro bloco.

```js
var plan = 10;
var blocos = [];
var resultados = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= 52; i++) {
    resultados.push(plan * i);
    if (i % 4 === 0) {
        blocos.push(resultados);
        resultados = [];
    }
}

var somaResultados = blocos.map(resultados => resultados.reduce((a, b) => a + b));
var somaBloco = somaResultados.reduce((a, b) => a + b);

console.log('blocos', blocos);
console.log('somaResultados', somaResultados);
console.log('somaBloco', somaBloco);
```

Agora para somar os resultados, você pode usar o método reduce. Apenas forneça uma função `callback` e retorne a soma do resultado acumulado (a) com o próximo item (b).

Comment: A ideia nesse codigo é tentar "replicar" a planilha de 52 semanas, os 13 blocos seriam os meses (lembrando que teria um 13° mes que n tem no calendário), a separação seria mais por questão de organização, e a soma seria do valor que seria dado do inicio a cada semana.. Mas o jeito que voce fez ja me deu uma luz, ainda estou aprendendo tentei replicar essa planilha apenas como exercicio pra aprender mais rapido.